# Privilege synonym page has a dead link

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, privileges

The [privilege synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) has a link to "https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/retag-questions" which doesn't exist any more.  It guess [2000 edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) is what it is replaced with.  Some sort of text explaining the alternative is *editing all the questions to update the tags* might also be useful.  And maybe the fact that a tag with zero questions will be gone in 24hrs?  Or maybe there is some good SO meta post to link to?

Comment: I'm taking a look at this now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I have [edited the help post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) by making the wording a bit clearer and fixing the dead link.